# java restrict List items

Tags: java

I am new to java. I have 5000 items in a list. I want to loop through the list so that I can get  100 items at a time. I have the following code:

```
   List<ProcessQueueBatch> processQueueBatchList = 
        Repository.getProcessQueue("Jor");
for (ProcessQueueBatch queueBatch : processQueueBatchList) 

   {
    // do some processing



   }
```

I want to do the processing of first 100 items in the list and then the next 100 items and then again next 100 items until all 5000 items are processed. I have total 5000 items in the list. How can I modify my for loop or list so that I can get 100 items at a time.

any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: A cycle of iteration only tackles *one* element at a time by default.  Unless you want to do some weird list slicing, I'm not sure I see much value in this approach.

Comment: You can define an index variable an using `if` condition to help you seperate the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`List.subList(int, int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#subList%28int,%20int%29) to get the first `K` items from your `processQueueBatchList` like so:

```
int K = 100;
List<ProcessQueueBatch> newList = new ArrayList<>(processQueueBatchList.subList(0, K));
```

You should be able to take it from here...

Answer (score 0):

If your choice of `List` supports it, there's always [List::subList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#subList-int-int-).

There's also implementations using `Stream`s.  For example:

```
myList.stream()
        .skip(10) // Skip the first 'n' elements.
        .limit(100) // Limit the return size.
        .collect(Collectors.toList()); // Collect however you see fit.
```

Which would be helpful if you needed to do some filtering, as well.